# Digit sum in Prolog

Tags: numbers, prolog, clpfd

How can I define in [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) the rule to calculate the [digit sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) of an integer?

Example:

```
digitsum[Integer, Result] :- ...
```

so that the query `digitsum(123, X).` results in `X = 6` (=1+2+3). A solution running under [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org) is appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted anything? Also,1digitsum[Integer, Result]` is improper syntax in Prolog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem naturally leads to an implementation using `library(clpfd)`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

digitsum(Z,S) :-
   Z #= 0,
   S #= 0.
digitsum(Z0, S0) :-
   Z0 #> 0, S0 #> 0,
   S0 #= Z0 mod 10 + S1,
   Z1 #= Z0 // 10,  % should be rather div
   digitsum(Z1, S1).

?- digitsum(D,S).
   D = S, S = 0
;  D = S, S in 1..9
;  D in 10..99, D/10#=_A, D mod 10#=_B,
   _A in 1..9, _B+_A#=S, _B in 0..9, S in 1..18
;  ... .
```

The first answer is about zero. The second says that a number 1..9 is the same as its sum.
Then it talks about the numbers 10..99 etc.

Comment: @mat: `div` is not in SWI ; the answers must not contain `/` but either `//` or `div` - accordingly.

Comment: Thx, using your answer exactly, I get an error with the example query: `ERROR: Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `123//10'`. Anything I do wrong?

Comment: @user2030503: You have a very old version of clpfd. You can use `/` instead *à la rigueur*

Comment: Thanks, the code with `Z1 #= Z0 / 10,` works now but there's still an issue that compiling the buffer throughs a warning: `... is always true: var(Z1).` Is the a clean solution? The issue persists even if I have updated the Mac SWI Prolog to latest stable version v6.6.6.

Comment: @user2030503: Forget that warning: It was/is an issue with the overzealous compiler.